# Open invisible activity on share action (ACTION_SEND)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-sharing

There are a lot of similar questions on StackOverfow but they don't solve my problem.

The task is to process in Service intents sent with default share mechanism (ACTION_SEND) from different applications.
But as far as `ACTION_SEND` is an activity action we have to pick up intent in activity and broadcast it to service. And it will be perfect if this activity will be invisible to the user.

I've researched a lot and have tried many solutions already.

1. First step of making activity invisible belongs to activity style.

   I've tried this values.

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

   Also i"ve tried to create a custom theme.

   ```
   <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
       <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
   </style>
   ```

   How the activity in AndroidManifest.xml looks like.

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="xxx.xxx.activities.HandleShareIntentActivity"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
       android:noHistory="true"
       android:excludeFromRecents="true"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_handle_share_intent">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.gm.action.AUTO_SEND"/>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="com.google.android.voicesearch.SELF_NOTE"/>
          <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. Activity code. No `setContentView()`. `finish()` in `onCreate()`.

   ```
   public class HandleShareIntentActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           startService(new Intent(this, xxxService.class).putExtra(
           Constants.ACTION_SHARE_KEY, getIntent()));

           finish();
       }  
    }
   ```

**On Nexus 5, android 4.4.4 I do have black screen blink while handling any share event.

Any solutions?**

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried this values.

Use `Theme.NoDisplay`.

Comment: Still blinks with black screen on share action. But Theme.NoDisplay works for me when I handling UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED event, activity is not visible and not blinking. And they are doing the same thing - send intent to service and finishes. But for share action Theme.NoDisplay doesn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nicolausYes: Since I have never seen `Theme.NoDisplay` open a window (i.e., "blinks with black screen"), I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Very short video to demonstrate a problem - http://youtu.be/uyC_8Q5SFSY Activity do have a `Theme.NoDisplay` style. Even If I do nothing in this activity (only `finish()` call), It "blinks" too.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the chooser, as that's one of the differences between your two scenarios. Try manually invoking your `ACTION_SEND` `Theme.NoDisplay` activity and see what happens. If it behaves as you want, then your problem is really with the chooser, and perhaps switching to a `ShareActionProvider` will give you better results. If you still get the black-screen blink, then it has to be something with your activity setup (e.g., custom theme changes).

Comment: I've tried what you suggested. First of all, I've manually invoked `ACTION_SEND` `Theme.NoDisplay` activity and it behaves as expected. It is invisible and I don't see any blink. I was thinking that the problem is in the chooser because sometimes if I press Share and then back button it blinks with black (checkout this example http://youtu.be/Xn8B7nY9he4). But when I share content with almost any other application (but not all, check this example – http://youtu.be/ptnvQ6P04A0) it doesn't blink. Maybe they know how to handle this situation? What it can be?

Comment: @nicolausYes: I have never tried having a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity be triggered by a chooser, so I haven't a clue, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I Just did this, and it helped in my case:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SensorBoardActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true">
```

I see you already have `finish();` but just for others it is important to execute it just before leaving the `onCreate()`.